# How to upload a picture from external storage to imageView

Tags: java, android, storage, external

Good day!

I upload a picture by URL and save it in the external storage in folder "Download"

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/ImageFolder/"  + "/" + "ImageTest" + ".png");
```

After that, I need to download the downloaded image in ImageView. I do it like this

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/ImageFolder/" + "ImageTest.png");
Picasso.get().load(directory).into(mIVImage);
```

As I understand the error somewhere in the path.

> **MyLog: /storage/emulated/0/Download/ImageFolder/ImageTest.png**

There is nothing along this "path".

[here](https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148), I tried to do as the link above.

I ask for your help.

Comment: you mean, you want to show downloaded image in `imageview`.

Comment: Please show the log!

Comment: @farhana yes, I want to install the downloaded image in ImageView (mIVImage)

Comment: you need to download the image first and get the location of that image and set into the `ImageView` . what do you mean by install image? you want to keep that image in your app.

Comment: did you checked manually, Did you find the image there ?

Comment: @farhana I just want to put the downloaded image in ImageView. but I can not correctly set the "path" to the image

Comment: @SRBbans yes, image is downloaded where needed

Comment: Read this about external storage. Almost everyone face this issue because of a misconception.  https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html

Comment: you are misunderstood.... how can you know later which image you have downloaded whereas want to show in app..you need a custom folder where you can save your all data and access for later use.

Comment: what is the image size ?

Comment: @farhana I create a folder “ImageFolder” and save an image with a certain name in this folder. That is, the folder name and file name I already know.

Comment: @SRBbans 300 bytes

Comment: get the path of download folder follow with your custom path and set into the imageview.

Comment: 300 bytes ? really ? not even 1 kb ?

Comment: please check image file is exit or not then set to the imageview.

Comment: @farhana Thank you! I will check